# Computing mean for non-unique elements of numpy array pairs

Tags: python, numpy

I have three arrays, all of the same size:

```
arr1 = np.array([1.4, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0])
arr2 = np.array([2.3, 5.0, 2.3, 2.3, 4.0, 6.0, 5.0, 6.0])
data = np.array([5.4, 7.1, 9.5, 1.9, 8.7, 1.8, 6.1, 7.4])
```

arr1 can take up any float value and arr2 only a few float values. I want to obtain the unique pairs of arr1 and arr2, e.g.

```
arr1unique = np.array([1.4, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0])
arr2unique = np.array([2.3, 5.0, 2.3, 4.0, 6.0, 5.0])
```

For each non-unique pair I need to average the corresponding elements in the `data`-array, e.g. averaging the values 9.5 and 1.9 since the pair `(arr1[3], arr2[3])` and `(arr1[4], arr2[4])` are equal. The same holds for the values in data corresponding to the indices 6 and 8. The data array therefore becomes

```
dataunique = np.array([5.4, 7.1, 5.7, 8.7, 4.6, 6.1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultdict` can help you here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array([1.4, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0])
>>> arr2 = np.array([2.3, 5.0, 2.3, 2.3, 4.0, 6.0, 5.0, 6.0])
>>> data = np.array([5.4, 7.1, 9.5, 1.9, 8.7, 1.8, 6.1, 7.4])
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x1, x2, d in zip(arr1, arr2, data):
...   dd[x1, x2].append(d)
... 
>>> arr1unique = np.array([x[0] for x in dd.iterkeys()])
>>> arr2unique = np.array([x[1] for x in dd.iterkeys()])
>>> dataunique = np.array([np.mean(x) for x in dd.itervalues()])
>>> print arr1unique
[ 1.4  7.   4.   9.   9.   3. ]
>>> print arr2unique
[ 2.3  4.   2.3  5.   6.   5. ]
>>> print dataunique
[ 5.4  8.7  5.7  6.1  4.6  7.1]
```

This method gives your answer, but destroys the ordering.  If the ordering is important, you can do basically the same thing with `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the collections library before. I don't have python 2.7 here (so I can't use OrderedDict), but the order is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 'pure numpy' solution to the problem. Pure numpy in quotes because it relies on a numpy enhancement proposal which I am still working on, but you can find the full code here:

http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp

```
group_by((arr1, arr2)).mean(data)
```

Voila, problem solved. Way faster than any of the posted solutions; and much more elegant too, if I may say so myself ;).

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary from arr1 as key and store its equivalent arr2 as value.for each save to dictionary generate its dataunique entry.If key already exists skip that iteration and continue.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to is to create a `OrderedDict` to store the keys as pair of elements in (arr1,arr2) and the values as a list of elements in data. For any duplicate key (pair of arr1 and arr2), the duplicate entries would be stored in the list. You can then re-traverse the values in the dictionary and create the average. To get the unique keys, just iterate over the keys and split the tuples

Try the following

```
>>> d=collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for k1,k2,v in zip(arr1,arr2,data):
    d.setdefault((k1,k2),[]).append(v)      
>>> np.array([np.mean(v) for v in d.values()])
array([ 5.4,  7.1,  5.7,  8.7,  4.6,  6.1])

>>> arr1unique = np.array([e[0] for e in d])
>>> arr2unique = np.array([e[1] for e in d])
```

Comment: Nice and short, although for some reason we still don't have python 2.7 here. I will have to stick to the solution of @wim.